# asymptotic relationship between numbers of scalar multiplications in matrix product (AB)C and A(BC)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, matrices, asymptotics

> Two functions $f(n,m,k,l) : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^+$ and $g(n,m,k,l): \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfy $f(n,m,k,l) \in \Theta(g(n,m,k,l))$ if there exist (real) constants $c_1,c_2,n_0,m_0,k_0,l_0 > 0$ so that for all $n\ge n_0, m\ge m_0, k\ge k_0, l\ge l_0$, we have $c_1g(n,m,k,l) \leq f(n,m,k,l)\leq c_2 g(n,m,k,l)$. Let $f(n,m,k,l)$ and $g(n,m,k,l)$ be the number of scalar multiplications when multiplying matrices $A,B,C$ in the following orders: $(AB)C$ and $A(BC)$. Here $A, B,C$ are $n\times m, m\times k,k\times l$ matrices respectively. Determine with proof, whether $f(n,m,k,l) \in \Theta(g(n,m,k,l)).$

I think $f(n,m,k,l) = nk(m+l)$ and $g(n,m,k,l) = ml(k+n)$, because when multiplying matrices $A$ and $B$ there are $nkm$ scalar multiplications, and then to multiply $(AB)C$ there are an additional $nkl$ scalar multiplications ($k$ for each of the $nl$ entries of $(AB)C$, assuming $AB$ has been computed already). However, I'm not sure how to show that there exist constants $c_1,c_2,n_0,m_0, k_0,l_0$ so that for all $n\ge n_0, m\ge m_0, k\ge k_0, l\ge l_0, c_1 g(n,m,k,l)\leq f(n,m,k,l) \leq c_2 g(n,m,k,l).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not true that $f(n,m,k,l) \in \Theta(g(n,m,k,l))$.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, there exist constants $c_1,c_2,n_0,m_0,k_0,l_0 > 0$ so that for all $n\ge n_0, m\ge m_0, k\ge k_0, l\ge l_0$, we have $c_1g(n,m,k,l) \leq f(n,m,k,l)\leq c_2 g(n,m,k,l)$.

Let $u = \lceil\max(n_0,m_0, k_0, l_0)\rceil$, $t=\lceil c_2\rceil+1$,
$n=tu$, $m = u$, $k = tu$, $l=u$. Then

$$\frac{f(n,m,k,l)}{g(n,m,k,l)}=\frac{nk(m+l)}{ml(k+n)}=\frac{2t^2u^3}{2tu^3}=t > c_2,$$
which contradicts the requirement that $f(n,m,k,l) \leq c_2 g(n,m,k,l)$.